# Javascript code execution going inside if condition even though condition is false

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is one of the weirdest behavior I have seen. Following is the js code snippet:

```
else if ($("*[id$=ddlDefaultPurpose]").val() == 2) {
    if ($("*[id$=ddlJobCategory]").val() == -1) {
        ShowMessageStrip(errorJobCategory);
        formIsValid = false;
    }
    //else if (!TryParseSalaryOffered($("*[id$=txtCurrentSalary]").val())) {
    //    ShowMessageStrip(errorCurrentSalary);
    //    formIsValid = false;
    //}
}
```

Now when the code executes, `$("*[id$=ddlJobCategory]").val()` is not equal to -1. And this can be seen clearly in Firebug. Now what happens is that the after the evaluating the condition, the code should come out, but instead it goes to the line `formIsValid = false`. It skips the `ShowMessageStrip(errorJobCategory)`.

Why could this be happening?

Comment: Are you sure it goes to that line? Did you verify in Firebug: set a breakpoint and saw it hit? Maybe, the value of `formIsValid` is `false` before you run your code?

Comment: have you got a fiddle for this?

Comment: Yes, I debugged in Firebug and that is where I see the code follow the execution path I described.

Comment: Can you please post more of your code? My initial hunch is that formIsValid is set to false in another area. Have you tried a console.log() or alert() inside of the block to see if formIsValid is actually being set there?

Comment: @naveen Not yet, let me see if I can get this in a fiddle

Comment: seeing the $ attribute selector i guess its our good old asp,.net. don't worry just view source and copy the relevant parts to jsfiddle and then add your script

Comment: Btw, what's the difference between `$("*[id$=ddlJobCategory]")` and `$("[id$=ddlJobCategory]")` (without asterisk `*`)? And could the reason be that you have more than one control returned by this `*[id$=ddlJobCategory]` query?

Comment: @Michael Sagalovich - it is entirely possible, because .val() only returns the value from the first element in the jquery collection

Comment: @bstakes Yes, by stepping through the code in Firebug I saw the behavior I have described above.

Comment: @Michael Sagalovich  There is only one control in the page which matches the selector $("*[id$=ddlJobCategory]")

Answer (score 0):

Stating the obvious, it sounds like your code isn't running the way you think.

Are you sure you don't have `=` instead of `==` somewhere? Are you sure your brackets are all matched (in code not shown here)? Trying checking in jslint.

Where is formIsValid declared? It looks like a global in the code here.

Also, are you sure ShowMessageStrip() isn't being called -- have you tried putting a console.log (and nothing else) in the function?